# Custom validation Rails for boolean attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add custom validation to my AR model: there is Order model with 'approved' attribute - this attribute cannot be approved twice. It's boolean attribute. I don't understand how can I check if this attribute has been approved already.

```
validate :cannot_be_approved_twice

  def cannot_be_approved_twice
    errors[:base] << ERROR_MSG if ...
  end
```

How can I check it? Thanks!

Comment: If `approved = true` then is it approved or it can be `false` also?

Comment: When Order is being created it has approved=false. Then Order can be approved, i.e. approved=true. After it I want to disable ability make order.update!(approved: true).

Comment: @malcoauri but that doesn't change the model anyway. It's a transition from one valid state to another (the same). Validation is intended to catch invalid states. What meaning does that "approval" have so it can (but shouldn't) be cast multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If it is `approved` already then the value of that field would be something and not `nil` so you can do it like this:

```
def cannot_be_approved_twice
  errors[:base] << ERROR_MSG unless approved.nil?
end
```

And if suppose it would have `true` value if it is approved then you can do:

```
def cannot_be_approved_twice
  errors[:base] << ERROR_MSG if approved
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first case is not for me. The second case - but if approved was false, and I want to update for true, it doesn't work and I get exception

Comment: I added your second option to my model. Then I created new Order (by default approved=false) and tried to make order.update!(approved: true) and I get ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer attaching the error to the approved attribute, so the error would be something like this

```
validate :prevent_double_approval, if: :some_check

def prevent_double_approval
  errors[:approved] << "can't be approved more than once" if approved?
end
```

This `some_check` method should be true when you detect that the user is trying to change the value, then the inner check `if approved?` checks if the value is already true before that second approval.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking previous value in your validation. Something like this:

```
def cannot_be_approved_twice
  errors[:approved] << "can't be approved more than once" unless self.approved_was.nil?
end
```

The "_was" postfix gives the value before the update. So, if it was not nil then someone has set it to true or false (meaning approved or disapproved).

**Update**

I read through your comments and realized that what when order is created it is set to false (initially, I thought that it is set to nil, so you could approve or disapprove it). Thus, if the field initially set to false, then the method above becomes:

```
def cannot_be_approved_twice
  errors[:approved] << "can't be approved more than once" if self.approved_was # if approved field was true (approved)
end
```

One more thing, with the way you are doing order update (order.update!(), with the bung), and your order has been approved then your application will fail with validation error because bung(!) explicitly tells application to fail in case of validation errors. You probably want to use just the "update" method and not "update!".